# Differentiability of a function at a point where a vertical tangent can be drawn

Tags: calculus, derivatives, definition

I know that a function is said to be diffentiableat a point if a tangent exists at that point .

So, when I saw a example where there was a vertical tangent and then also it's answer said it's non differentiable!!

Why a function is not differentiable at a point even though there exist vertical tangent at that point? For example consider $(2x-5)^{1/3}$ at $x=5/2$.

Comment: Can you give an example of such a point, noting that $(x, \infty)$ is not a point?

Comment: Forget about geometrical definitions of the derivative, they're problematic in edge cases. Use the proper (analytical) definition.

Comment: @Paul you can consider tangent at inflection point.

Comment: @Git Gud : Ok I got the point in this case both the derivatives exist ,but are not finite.

Comment: @Rover realized $x^{\frac{1}{3}}$ would work but thought I'd take my punishment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The derivative is the slope of the tangent line, and the slope of a vertical line does not exist.